# Failed to access data stream for resource in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, smooks

I am using smooks api for java-xml and xml-java converting.this code is working in jboss4.2.2 but to migrate jboss7.1.1 getting exception is "Failed to access data stream for resource"

Sample Code:

```
private String runSmooksTransform(Object inputJavaObject)
        throws IOException, SAXException {
              Smooks smooks = new Smooks("/WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml");
            try {
        ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        smooks.filterSource(executionContext,
                new org.milyn.payload.JavaSource(inputJavaObject),
                new StreamResult(writer));

        return writer.toString();
        } finally {
        smooks.close();
         }
         }
```

smooks-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.0.xsd" >

    <resource-config selector="global-parameters">
        <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    </resource-config>


</smooks-resource-list>
```

module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.milyn">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="milyn-smooks-all-1.4.jar"/>
</resources>

 <dependencies>
   <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
  <module name="org.jaxen" />
   <module  name="org.hibernate" slot="3" />

  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Exception :

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to access data stream for resource [/WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml]. Tried (in order):
10:10:14,113 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   File System: E:\WEB-INF\smooks-config.xml
10:10:14,114 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   File System: E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\WEB-INF\smooks-config.xml
10:10:14,117 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   Classpath: /WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml
10:10:14,125 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 

10:10:14,126 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.milyn.resource.URIResourceLocator.getResource(URIResourceLocator.java:130)

10:10:14,128 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.milyn.resource.URIResourceLocator.getResource(URIResourceLocator.java:84)

10:10:14,129 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.milyn.Smooks.addConfigurations(Smooks.java:307)

10:10:14,131 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.milyn.Smooks.<init>(Smooks.java:151)

10:10:14,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at com.manam.mobee.customer.MobeeCustomerHome.runSmooksTransform(MobeeCustomerHome.java:644)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about smooks, but my guess is it's using it's class loader to attempt to find the resource at the path you're sending it. Since you have smooks in a module it's using it's own `ModuleClassLoader` that can't see what's in the class loader for your deployment. You're best to use the `java.io.InputStream` constructor.

If you're running this from a servlet you can use the `javax.servlet.ServerContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/smokes-config.xml")`.

Comment: In Smooks  Smooks smooks = new Smooks(resourceURI); its loads the access path.in that they use InpuStream .

Comment: Yes, but I think you need to provide the InputStream. It's likely the module (org.milyn) is using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`which won't work.

Comment: by default smooks is accepting this path  E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\WEB-INF\smooks-config.xml ,how should i change the runtime path for /WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml ?

Comment: i was tried  smooks.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml"); its won't work getting null value.

Comment: Since the `smooks-config.xml` is on your deployments class path you need to get the configuration file from the deployments class loader. The smooks module class loader will not be able to find a configuration file on your deployments class path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the relative path in this part: `Smooks smooks = new Smooks("/WEB-INF/smooks-config.xml")` to absolute path:)